# Case insensitive search in Mongodb

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb

I am trying a case insensitive search in Mongo. Basically I want case insensitive string match I am using regex. Here is my code

```
Query query = new Query( Criteria.where(propName).regex(value.toString(), "i"));
```

But the above dosent match my whole string(a string sometime with spaces). It returns values even if its a substring.

Eg: Suppose my collection has 2 values "Bill" and "Bill status',It returns me "bill" even if my search is "bill status". It returns results even if the there is a sub string of the string I am searching for

I tried , `Query query = new Query( Criteria.where(propName).is(value.toString()));`

But the above is case sensitive. Can someone please help on this.

Comment: So your actual question is not how to control case sensitivity but rather how to match the complete input and not just the input as a substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn't pinned to front and back for equivalence. Pass the value in like:

```
foo: /^VALUE$/i
```

The caret pins the string to the front for full text match with case insensitivity.